# Python: sum of values greater than last value

Tags: python, list

Problem:

> Write a program that will loop through a list and sum all values greater than the last
>   value in the list. If there are no values greater than the list or if the list is empty, return -1.

My Code:

```
def go(list1):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(list1)-1):
        if list1[i] < list1[i+1]:
            total+=list1[i+1]
            count += 1
        else:
            total += 0
        if count is 0:
            total = -1
        if len(list1) == 1:
            total = -1
    return total

print(go( [-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5] ))
print(go( [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,-99] ))
print(go( [10,20,30,40,50,-11818,40,30,20,10] ))
print(go( [32767] ))
print(go( [255,255] ))
print(go( [9,10,-88,100,-555,2] ))
print(go( [10,10,10,11,456] ))
print(go( [-111,1,2,3,9,11,20,1] ))
print(go( [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2,6] ))
print(go( [12,15,18,21,23,1000] ))
print(go( [250,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,0] ))
print(go( [9,10,-8,10000,-5000,-3000] ))
```

My Output:

```
55
-1
180
0
-1
112
466
46
5
1077
-1
7010
```

Desired Output:

```
55
-1
180
-1
-1
112
466
46
5
1077
-1
7010
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is that output 0 instead of -1?

Comment: Because 0 is the default and you never made it inside your loop to change it?

Comment: @csmckelvey I added code so if the length of the list is 1 then the output would be -1

Comment: But that is inside the loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm not entirely following you but if you have the list [-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5] and want to sum all numbers greater than the last element, which is 5, your subsetted list would be [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] which sums to 40, not 55. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RobertMilletich oops! I actually want to sum the values in the list that are greater than the previous value in the list.

Comment: @RobertMilletich Instead of "last value" I think it means "previous value".  [-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5] becomes  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] which sums to 55.

Comment: Why is there this condition: `list1[i] < list1[i+1]`? It is inconsistent with your problem description.

Comment: @JenkinsMa okay that makes more sense!

Comment: @JenkinsMa 
wgy the ninth answer is 5 ?, it should be 6 since in the list [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0, -2,6] only 6 is greater than its predecessor, because what would be the only element and the sum would be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the list you put in has a length of 1 you iterate through the for loop zero times.

That means any code you put in there to check on the conditions will never get executed. I personally like to return as soon as you can, so I would recommend the following:

```
def go(list1):
  if len(list1) == 1:
      return -1
  total = 0
  count = 0
  for i in range(0,len(list1)-1):
      if list1[i] < list1[i+1]:
          total+=list1[i+1]
          count += 1
  if count is 0:
      return -1
  return total
```

Answer (score 1):

Rule of Thumb: Always check the corner cases first, and then do further processing

```
def go(list1):
    total = 0
    # no need for extra int variable, bool will do the job.
    greater_found = False

    # this condition will cover for list with single or no(empty list) element
    if len(list1) < 2:
        return -1

    for i in range(1, len(list1)):
        if list1[i] > list1[i-1]:
            total = total + list1[i]
            greater_found = True

    if not greater_found:
        return -1

    return total
```